# Hyperloop is re-writing source JS then failing subsequent clean builds

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-hyperloop

I've just updated to the latest 5.2.0.GA and am trying a simple Hyperloop test app.

Building the app causes references to hyperloop code in the source JavaScript to be re-written. Then it will fail the next rebuild due to `Skipping Hyperloop compile, no usage found ...` error, since JS code was re-written...

Reference [here](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/appc-labs-server/downloads/Hyperloop+for+iOS+Programming+Guide.pdf) and [here](http://labs.appcelerator.com/project/55f74a9f421c44837717716b/Hyperloop-Module)

Environment :

```
    OS X     : 10.10.5
    node -v  : v0.12.7
    Studio   : 4.5.0.201602170821
    TiSDK    : 5.2.0.GA 
    ti -v    : 5.0.6
    appc -v  : 5.2.0
    hyperloop: 1.1.0
```

1. Create new Classic Single Window Application mobile app project. Test build.
2. Add hyperloop requirements to tiapp.xml

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>hyperloop</plugin>
    </plugins>
    <modules>
        <module>hyperloop</module>
    </modules>
```

and

```
    <ios>
        <run-on-main-thread>true</run-on-main-thread>
        <use-jscore-framework>true</use-jscore-framework>
    </ios>
```

3. As per example code in the "[Hyperloop for iOS Programming Guide](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/appc-labs-server/downloads/Hyperloop+for+iOS+Programming+Guide.pdf)" PDF, I attempted to add a simple red UIView. ( In /Resources/ui/common/FirstView.js )

```
    //FirstView Component Constructor
    function FirstView() {
        //create object instance, a parasitic subclass of Observable
        var self = Ti.UI.createView();

        //label using localization-ready strings from /i18n/en/strings.xml
        var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            color:'#000000',
            text:String.format(L('welcome'),'Titanium'),
            height:'auto',
            width:'auto'
        });
        self.add(label);

        //Add behavior for UI
        label.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            alert(e.source.text);
        });

        // Test native view 
        var UIView = require('UIKit/UIView'),
        UIColor = require('UIKit/UIColor'),
        CGRectMake = require('CoreGraphics').CGRectMake;

        var view = UIView.alloc().initWithFrame(CGRectMake(0,0,100,100));
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
        self.add(view);

        return self;
    }
    module.exports = FirstView;
```

4. In terminal, run : `appc ti build -p ios -f`

The app launches. A small red view is seen in the top left corner.

All good.

**BUT** when I look back at the source JavaScript FirstView.js, the references to the native UIView, UIColor and CGRectMake have been edited.  (I also notice that the build process created `hyperloop` folder within the Resources folder containing what appears to be the location of the newly edited references:

```
    var UIView = require('hyperloop/uikit/uiview'),
    UIColor = require('hyperloop/uikit/uicolor'),
    CGRectMake = require('hyperloop/coregraphics/coregraphics').CGRectMake;
```

**NOW** when trying to build the app again using 
`appc ti build -p ios -f`  - the build fails with this error during the Hyperloop assembly :

```
    ...
    [INFO]  Starting Hyperloop assembly
    [INFO]  Skipping Hyperloop compile, no usage found ...
    An uncaught exception was thrown!
    callback is not defined
    callback is not defined
```

Anyone have any ideas? I know this is beta, but am I missing a flag?

**BONUS BUG**: The `-f` force clean build flag does not appear to be cleaning out the `build/hyperloop` folder.

Comment: Jira ticket here : https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20469

Comment: on the **BONUS BUG** - the `-f` flag is described as _force a full rebuild_. It will force the Xcode project to be rebuild, just as when you change a `tiapp.xml` property. It is not the same as `ti clean`.

Comment: Somehow I think it might be related to the encapsulated function. If you clean everything and just run the code directly (making self a `Ti.UI.Window` and opening it), does that change something? Anyway it should work both ways.

Comment: I'll give it a go. BTW: Should we be using 1.1.0 or 1.0.1 of the plugin?  I noticed you reverted back to an older version in the hyperloop-examples project.